# Is it possible to change the device of docker named volume without loosing data?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have multiple named volumes created with the following docker-compose:

```
  gitlab:
    restart: always
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
    volumes:
    - gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab
    - gitlab-log:/var/log/gitlab
    - gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab

volumes:
  gitlab-config:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/docker-compose/volumes/gitlab-config
  gitlab-log:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/docker-compose/volumes/gitlab-log
  gitlab-data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /srv/docker-compose/volumes/gitlab-data
```

I want to change the `device:` value on each volume without loosing data within those volumes.

If I simply do `docker-compose down`, copy the directory specified in the `device` to the new location (`/new-path/volumes/gitlab-data`) and change yaml to point to that new location (`device: /new-path/volumes/gitlab-data`), then, after `docker-compose up -d` receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: Configuration for volume gitlab-config specifies "device" driver_opt /srv/docker-compose/volumes/gitlab-config, but a volume with the same name uses a different "device" driver_opt (/srv/docker-compose/volumes/redmine-mariadb-data). If you wish to use the new configuration, please remove the existing volume "project_gitlab-config" first:
$ docker volume rm project_gitlab-config
```

What is the correct way of backing up those volumes and changing the volumes' paths without loosing the data within those volumes?

Comment: This question would fit better on ServerFault.

Comment: You might try with a less-critical example, but it should be safe to `docker-compose down -v` to "delete" the Docker named volumes that get created.  That should delete the mount points in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` and other similar Docker-internal details, but leave the host directories intact.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your reply. Do I understand you correctly, that `docker-compose down -v` will not remove volumes, but just the mount point/device information within docker and will not remove the data within host binds (like `/srv/docker-compose/volumes/gitlab-config`)? Would it make sense then to simply do `docker-compose down`, copy those old directories to the new location (`cp -r /srv/docker-compose/volumes/gitlab-config /new-path/volumes/gitlab-config`) then delete old volumes as docker sugests (`docker volume rm project_gitlab-config`) change docker-compose.yml and do up -d?

Answer (score 0):

One option, and it's one I do often, is to simply do a fresh backup of the named volume, then delete the current named volume, set up the new volume however you want, with whatever name you want, etc., and then import the data from the backup into it:

```
# Backup
docker run --rm -v volume_name:/volume -v c:\migrate:/backup alpine tar -cjf /backup/backup.tar.bz2 -C /volume ./
```

```
# Restore
docker run --rm -v volume_name:/volume -v c:\migrate:/backup alpine tar -C /volume/ -xjf /backup/backup.tar.bz2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Is there a way to backup all three volumes of my gitlab container in one docker command, or is it only possible to do it for each individual volume?

Comment: @Drew afaik it has to be individually, but when i want to do a bunch at once i put them in a .sh script (or .bat for Windows).